# Modeling SQL schema to DynamoDB

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb, database-schema

In my project AWS Lambda is scraping data from e-shop on daily bases and saving them to MySQL.

Since I want to be more cost-effective I want to use DynamoDB.

**How I want to query?**

- by **productId** (thats clear)
- by **categories** (with newest scraped product_data - **prices, ratings, etc.**) - means all product in categories **father, kitchen and knifes**

Is this case suitable for Dynamo? How would model looked like?

I have three approaches in mind, but every one have disadvantage:

1. Have **two tables** first for product with scraped data, second with categories with products. This means 1st query to figure out products in category, second to fetch product data + two tables in sync.
2. One table **Partition key on productId**, **sort key on timestamp** and for every scrape I would save **3 rows for product**, **for every category one row** and make GLI on category with timestamp as sort key. But if I have 100 product scraped daily, every is in 8 categories average, it would be 800 rows per day, just to have this many-to-many relationship. In month I would have **24k rows**. Let's say I want to delete one category from product after month, I would have to update 240 rows?
3. Or this case is not suited for DynamoDB, would be easier to stick with MySQL?

[image: Database Scheme]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have this as your table.

```
productId | sortKey         |  GSI1     |
1234232   | event#123232323 |           | price1  | orders1 | rating1 | rating_count1 | created_at1
1234232   | event#123232327 |           | price2  | orders2 | rating2 | rating_count2 | created_at2
1234232   | category#father | Father    | <other properties of category>
1234232   | category#kitchen| kitchen   | <other properties of category?>
```

here productid is secondary Key of GSI1.

This will solve the following use cases

1. For one product see the event history. (SELECT* where id=X and sortKey startswith event )
2. Get all category of a product. (SELECT* where id=X and sortKey startswith category )
3. Get all products with one category. (SELECT* where GSI1=x)
4. Remove one category from a product without updating many rows. (while doing an update get all existing categories if new add, if existing is not there remove and add particular event.)

Here is a nice [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEPXoXVf2k) explaining schema design.